# In R how do you randomly generate edges between nodes?

Tags: r, random, igraph

So currently I use the following code to randomly generate 30 nodes and 151 connections.

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(30, 151 , type = "gnm" , directed = F , loops = F)
```

But, I want to generate an empty graph then randomly generate 151 edges. How would I go about doing that? Is there a code that I can add to the one below?

```
g <- g <- graph.empty(30, directed = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following as demonstrated [at the bottom of this page](http://igraph.org/r/doc/plus-.igraph.html)

```
g <- graph.empty(30, directed = F)
number_of_edges = 151

g <- g + edges(sample(V(g), number_of_edges*2, replace = T), color = "red")
```

However, it seems you want to exclude loops. You could do that by sampling 2 nodes 151 times without replacement, for example as follows:

```
my_edges <- sapply(seq(number_of_edges),function(x) {sample(V(g),2,replace=F)})
g <- g + edges(my_edges, color = "red")
```

Hope this helps!

> EDIT: no duplicates edges.

To create a graph with no duplicate edges, you could first create all combinations, and then sample from those:

```
x <- combn(V(g),2)
my_edges <- x[,sample(seq(dim(x)[2]),number_of_edges,replace=F)]
g <- g + edges(my_edges, color = "red")
```

Comment: It worked great. However, I was wondering how could I remove the extra edges between two nodes. Because, occasionally when I run this code it creates an excess of edges between two nodes (2~4). How would I get rid of the extra edges and make them just 1 without taking away from the total edge count?

Comment: Hi Bill, I added an alternative solution to deal with that, hope that better solves your issue. If not, let me know!

Comment: Where do I include the "no duplicates" code? Because when I place it after the "151 sampling of 2 nodes" code, it appears to create twice the actual number of edges I desire?

Comment: It replaces the previous creation of my_edges, so make sure that you only do g <- g + edges only once.

Comment: While I was using this code, I wondered if there was a way to modify this code so that it becomes a set number of connections all arising from one node? (so let's say 20 connections from node 3)

Comment: Yes, that should be easy. however, I am currently on holiday without access to a laptop, so please consider posting this as a new question on SO and I'm sure someone else can help you with it. If not, Ill be back to answer it in two days ;)